# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError in Heroku Flask app - how to debug?

Tags: python, json, heroku, python-requests

I have built a heroku flask app, which is connecting to a web API for Dynamics 365. Every now and then my app crashes with following error (copy pasted from Heroku logs):

```
2021-03-09T12:08:51.463416+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=holmed.herokuapp.com request_id=16a135a9-7b41-4813-944d-f616551b4875 fwd="89.64.66.42" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=156ms status=500 bytes=385 protocol=https
2021-03-09T12:08:51.461297+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-03-09 12:08:51,460] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
2021-03-09T12:08:51.461320+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-03-09T12:08:51.461321+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
2021-03-09T12:08:51.461322+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
2021-03-09T12:08:51.461323+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
2021-03-09T12:08:51.461324+00:00 app[web.1]:     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
2021-03-09T12:08:51.461324+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
2021-03-09T12:08:51.461324+00:00 app[web.1]:     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
2021-03-09T12:08:51.461325+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
2021-03-09T12:08:51.461326+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise value
2021-03-09T12:08:51.461326+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
2021-03-09T12:08:51.461327+00:00 app[web.1]:     rv = self.dispatch_request()
2021-03-09T12:08:51.461327+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
2021-03-09T12:08:51.461327+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
2021-03-09T12:08:51.461328+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/app.py", line 222, in index
2021-03-09T12:08:51.461328+00:00 app[web.1]:     qualif = qualifications()[1]
2021-03-09T12:08:51.461329+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/query.py", line 877, in qualifications
2021-03-09T12:08:51.461329+00:00 app[web.1]:     df = json_normalize(crmres.json()["value"])
2021-03-09T12:08:51.461330+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 898, in json
2021-03-09T12:08:51.461330+00:00 app[web.1]:     return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
2021-03-09T12:08:51.461331+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
2021-03-09T12:08:51.461332+00:00 app[web.1]:     return _default_decoder.decode(s)
2021-03-09T12:08:51.461332+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
2021-03-09T12:08:51.461332+00:00 app[web.1]:     obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
2021-03-09T12:08:51.461333+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
2021-03-09T12:08:51.461333+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
2021-03-09T12:08:51.461340+00:00 app[web.1]: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
2021-03-09T12:08:51.462396+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.12.107.73 - - [09/Mar/2021:12:08:51 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 205 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.190 Safari/537.36"
```

Here is my code handling the communication with the API

```
tokentype, token = get_access_token()
bearer = f'{tokentype} {token}'
DATA_URL = f"https://holmed.crm4.dynamics.com/data/"
crm_web_api = 'https://holmed.api.crm4.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1'  # full path to web api endpoint

crm_request_headers = {
    'Authorization': bearer,
    'OData-MaxVersion': '4.0',
    'OData-Version': '4.0',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    'Prefer': 'odata.maxpagesize=500',
    'Prefer': 'odata.include-annotations=OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue'
}

def crm_read(query_string):
    return requests.get(crm_web_api + query_string, headers=crm_request_headers)

def qualifications():
    query_string = "/is_potentialpatients?$filter=statuscode%20eq%20100000001"
    crmres = crm_read(query_string)
    df = json_normalize(crmres.json()["value"]) # THE ERROR HAPPENS OVER HERE
    if df.empty:
        html = "Brak oczekujących na kwalifikacje."
        qualif = 0
    else:
        try:
            df = df[['is_name', 'is_phonenumber', 'is_comments', 'is_hospital@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue',
                 'is_referral_date']]
            df = df.rename(columns={'is_name': 'Nazwisko', 'is_phonenumber': 'Numer telefonu', 'is_comments': 'Uwagi',
                                'is_hospital@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue': 'Szpital kierujący',
                                'is_referral_date': 'Data ze skierowania'})
        except KeyError:
            df = df[['is_name', 'is_phonenumber', 'is_comments',
                 'is_referral_date']]
            df = df.rename(columns={'is_name': 'Nazwisko', 'is_phonenumber': 'Numer telefonu', 'is_comments': 'Uwagi','is_referral_date': 'Data ze skierowania'})

        df['Data ze skierowania'] = df['Data ze skierowania'].str.slice(start=0, stop=10)
        qualif = df['Nazwisko'].count()
        df = df.fillna("")
        html = df.to_html()
        html = html.replace("dataframe", "table table-hover table-sm")
        html = html.replace("None", "")
    return html, qualif

qualif = qualifications()[1]
print(qualif)
```

The URL I use for the API call works fine in the browser. My python code works fine when I execute it from the IDE. When I re-build my app on Heroku, it starts working again, only to break down after a couple of days throwing the above error.

I have reviewed all related questions on stack overflow, but none concerned specifically heroku, and I could not find any solution to the problem.

Any thoughts?

**Edit:** I have been asked for "debugging details". I have tried to reproduce this error by running the above code from my IDE. However, the code runs fine. Therefore, I am not sure what debugging details I can further provide... How would you debug this? :-)

Comment: the likley hood is that this `crmres.json()` is not returning JSON at least at the time when the evet crashes. Maybe log the crmres object before tyring to call json method on it and see what the content of it is.

Comment: I think you just need to improve your application logging to be able to debug what were the problems on production, just add logging to your app.

Comment: @mniebieski are you refreshing your Bearer token?

Comment: @GilSousa what do you mean by "refreshing"?

Comment: I mean that when the token expires it needs to be refreshed (changed for a new token). From your code I'm not sure if you create a bew token every time your script is executed or a new token is created when the flask server is run for the first time since we don't have your full code in display here.

Comment: From my understanding I am gettng a token each time script is run.

This is the get_access_token() function for further insight:
```
response = requests.post(LOGIN_URL, data={'tenant_id': TENANT_ID,
                                          'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
                                          'client_secret': CLIENT_SECRET,
                                          'grant_type': GRANT_TYPE,
                                          'resource': RESOURCE}).json()

def get_access_token():
    return response['token_type'], response['access_token']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to debug the issue, you need to improve your application logging. I would make the following changes to debug the problem:

```
def crm_read(query_string):
    print(crm_web_api + query_string)
    response = requests.get(crm_web_api + query_string, headers=crm_request_headers)
    print(response.status_code)
    return response

def qualifications():
    query_string = "/is_potentialpatients?$filter=statuscode%20eq%20100000001"
    crmres = crm_read(query_string)
    print(crmres.json())
    df = json_normalize(crmres.json()["value"]) # THE ERROR HAPPENS OVER HERE
```

If you are using Flask just replace the `print` statements with `app.logger.info` and lower the app logging level accordingly. And this should allow you to debug what is happening with your app on production.